# Flutter/Revenuecat: Check if user has already bought something

Tags: android, ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

i am currently building an app in Flutter using RevenueCat for the in-app-purchases.

I now want to know for each user, if he has already made an in-app-purchase, since I have trial subscriptions activated. I need this information, because I want to adjust the UI in case a user registers with a new account that I haven't seen in RevenueCat so far. In this case, he won't be able to use the trial subscription again, since Google/Apple prevent this.

I am using a custom ID for every user in my app and I use this ID for RevenueCat aswell, one could just create a new account and get a different user id. In this case, this looks like a "new" user to RevenueCat which has no subscriptions. I think the solution would have to check the GooglePlay-Account for an already purchased subscription

So far I have not found a way to find out, if a user has already made an in-app-purchase. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

I have tried to do this with https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase, but no luck so far. All the guides seem to be outdated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

based on official documentation

> **scenario**
> *Does not have any login mechanism and only relies on RevenueCat anonymous App User IDs.*

*solution*

> **Transfer purchases.**
> Required to allow customers to restore transactions after uninstalling / reinstalling your app.

just set that in your revenueCat dashboard
and it restores user purchases depending on

**google play account** or **apple id**

for more info -> https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/restoring-purchases#example-usage

Answer (score 0):

You can check Entitlements to determine if a user has an active subscription, more info here: https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/customer-info

It will go something like:

```
try {
  PurchaserInfo purchaserInfo = await Purchases.getPurchaserInfo();
  // access latest purchaserInfo
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  // Error fetching purchaser info
}
```

Then

```
if (purchaserInfo.entitlements.all["my_entitlement_identifier"].isActive) {
  // Grant user "pro" access
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have clarified my question a little bit more. Since I am using a custom ID for every user in my app and I use this ID for RevenueCat aswell, one could just create a new account and get a different user id. In this case, this looks like a "new" user to RevenueCat which has no subscriptions. I think the solution would have to check the GooglePlay-Account for an already purchased subscription.

Comment: Yes that's a bit more complicated, I know Google has released some improvements to subscriptions, sounds like you're on the right track!